# Firebird replication help needed

Tags: database, replication, firebird, database-replication, firebird2.5

I am writing a two way server - client Firebird replication with a C# app and I am facing the following problem.
I have a log table with the table name pk of the record and type of the query executet on it. For example if in the sales table there has been inserted a line with primery key of 4 there will be the table name, pk of the record and insert.
My idea is if the statement is insert to take every value from the client's DB and insert it into the server's. How do I do this and how to do it so that it can work fast. Should I devide every record by tables and select all unreplicated records from that table or there is some other way.

By the way I used the method where every query that has been executed is written in a fild in the log table, but that makes it impossible to add columns to the table, cos the query will be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start with some information from the IBExpert.net online documentation. This article explains the fundamentals of database replication with Firebird: http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.BidirectionalReplicationForInterBaseAndFirebird 
Moreover the IBExpert KG offers their own solutions for replication. You could skim their replication FAQs or get some information via email. http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ReplicationFAQs

Comment: Hello MBDev, Thank you for your answer. The replication method described in IBE site is an exact copy of mi current replication engine. The problem is, that it stores execu I U D query in a LOG table and then executes it on the server DB. This way if you add a column to the table, this query will not work. It will say that there are more columns in this table. The same is if I want to alter a field name or drop it. Thats why I want to be able to ger the record from the cliend DB and copy it to the server. I need help to do particularly this scheme.

Comment: Adding a coulmn shouldn't be a problem. Moreover updating a coulmn is possible, but it's not a good idea to change field names. **My tipps:** **1.** Just add the needed fields to your SQL. For instance: if (new.FIELD<>null) then SQL=SQL||'....'. An Update statement should just contain the changed fields and an ID. **2.** After doing meta changes add your SQL into the replication operation table. For instance SQLs like "ALTER TABLE....". This method allows to transfer meta changes in the correct order. **3.** Avoid deleting tables and fields.

Comment: **4.** Try to keep your clients synchronized. Sometimes this goal is a real challenge, but it makes meta changes simple.

Comment: First I want to thank you for your help. I am very greatful.

Comment: My main problem was that the triggers didn't insert in the log table inserts like "insert into TABLE (fields) values (values);", but instead "insert into TABLE values (values)". Add a column and it says "column number mismatch". 
So your recomendation is to change to first method as this will give me ability to add cols and after metadata change I should just recreate the thigges so that they insert according to the new columns?

Comment: First of all I don't understand why adding a new column should be a problem. **Please do not add not null fields in updates.** Let's say you got a table with MyField1. After some time you added Myfield2. Your outdated client dbs will generate a SQL like: insert into TABLE (MyField1) values ('Hi') If Myfield2 is not set, the database server will try to load the default value or null (default is not set). So all in all adding a column shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And it's also extremely helpful to generate the replication triggers automatically. All the needed information are stored in the system tables and you can create/alter triggers using execute statement commands (as SYSDBA or admin user)

Comment: Yes of course it shouldn't be not null. So this way I can only add columns or alter them to be bigger, but thats a start. Thank you that solves my problems for now.
Oh yeees of course I use a script to generate the triggers. My DB has 153 tables it's unthinkable to do it in any other way, cos if you change metadata you need to recreate the triggers ;).
Thank you very much for your help. :)